# Write to a .txt file in a package

Tags: java

I would like to write to a .txt file that is inside a package. I can get it to read from the exact location the .txt file is stored but not from inside the package. I'm assuming it is using class loaders but I cannot seem to get it to work. 
Here is what I have so far.

```
public void writeFile(String fileLocation) {
    Writer output = null;
    File file = new File(fileLocation);
    try {
        output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));  
        output.append("WRITING TEST");

     output.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
     System.out.println("Couldn't write to file.");

    }
}
```

Then I use this in another class to write.

```
WriteFile writeFile = new WriteFile();
writeFile.writeFile("src/com/game/scores.txt");
```

I understand that if using class loaders you remove "src/" because that will no longer exist when the program is compiled in a .jar.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Are you trying to write to a resource?

Comment: I am not sure that there is a generic way to do that for files within the Java package hierarchy. What if the file is within a JAR file?

Comment: The file will be inside the .jar file. I would like to write to it to update the scores in my game as the user goes through the levels.

Comment: You can't write to files inside jars

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14403745/write-to-file-method-in-jar

Comment: Uh, you are going to modify the JAR file? Just for keeping scores in a game? I cannot think of a way to do that, short of using ZipFile and treating the JAR as an archive...

Comment: Sorry! No wonder I couldn't find anything online about how to do it.

Comment: @user3080274: it's also not a very good idea. Code and variable data should not be forced together like this...

Comment: So if there is no way of writing to a txt file in a .jar, what is the best way to store the scores and access and update them?

Comment: @user3080274: For each operating system there is a convention on where user data like this is stored. Are those high scores supposed to be shared among users?

Comment: The game just needs to store whether the user gets bronze, silver, or gold. So there will just be scores stored for one user and that is all

Comment: Could I instead have a folder, which contains game.jar and scores.txt and then access the scores.txt to read it and write to it like that?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a class in that package to give you the location of the folder.
Try something like

```
public URL getPackageLocation() {
    return getClass().getResource(".");
}
```

This should give you the location of the folder from which this method is being called from.

Comment: You can get the location of a file within a .jar file this way (I've used it many times to call images and what not). However, I do not think you can edit a .txt file within a jar.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to write or update a file inside jar. Since jar itself is a file.

Please refer this link.

[Write To File Method In JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14403745/write-to-file-method-in-jar)

Answer (score 0):

From the comments you already know that you cann't write to a file, which resides in a JAR file. At best what you can do, is creating your file, relative to the path where the JAR is located like bellow:

```
 mylocation
          |-- my-jar.jar
          |-- com
                |--game
                      |--myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to write to it to update the scores in my game as the
>   user goes through the levels.

While it might be possible to [write to the JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21113073/maintaining-the-data-in-a-jar-file/21113192#21113192), I don't recommend it for this use case. Just write it somewhere at:

```
Path userdir = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".myApp", "<my app version>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't  write into Jar file. Writing into Jar file is not recommendable. You can write outside the jar file.

Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13937904/java-writing-to-txt-in-a-jar-file/13939133#13939133) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052311/how-can-an-app-use-files-inside-the-jar-for-read-and-write) stack overflow question for more details.